# Performance of adding entries to a static dictionary at runtime

Tags: c#, performance, memory, dictionary

When reading about static dictionaries, I noticed that since they are static there is only one copy in memory, but you can still add and remove from them. What is the performance hit for doing this? I assume that there could be one since the whole dictionary might be copied in memory. Is this correct or just a misconception?

Also, where would it be copied in memory if it was? Would it become a member of the class or would the changes made be accessible to all instances of the class instead of just the one making the modifications?

Comment: It sounds like you have a *lot* of misconceptions here. Add/Remove to a static dictionary works just like a normal one, the `static` just means its not associated with an instance of that class, but the `static` "instance". Could you perhaps clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bradley suggests, there may be deeper and more fundamental misunderstandings on your part as to how C# works. That said, it seems to me that your question is reasonably clear, in that you have expressed your misunderstandings related to the question, allowing them to be addressed.

1. Most important, is the direct answer to your question: no, there is no real performance difference using a dictionary object referenced by a static field as compared to a dictionary object referenced by an instance field.
2. Being a reference type (i.e. a `class`) a dictionary object, regardless of where it is referenced, will never be "copied in memory" without an explicit statement in code to do so. This is true of *all* reference type objects, not just dictionaries.
3. Being referenced by a static field, such a dictionary is accessible to any code that has access to the field (i.e. depending on the accessibility of the field, `private`, `protected`, `internal`, etc.), and any modification to the dictionary object will be visible to *all* code that has access to the object. Note that if code that has access to the field passes the object reference to code that does not have access to the field, even the code that does not have access to the field will still see the object, including any modifications made to it. That's how reference types work.

It's possible that the answers above will simply raise even more questions on your part, since they likely conflict with certain preconceptions you have about the way C# works and now you'll have to resolve those conflicts. I encourage you to start with the C# tutorials and documentation on MSDN, especially those related to how reference types work and how memory management works. Once you have corrected your misconceptions in those areas, the above answers will make more sense, and your overall understanding of how these kinds of things work will be much better.